# Android Add Cookie to MediaPlayer Requests

Tags: android

I'm attempting to play and HLS stream using the Android MediaPlayer.  I need the MediaPlayer to send a cookie with each request for an individual media segment.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of API Level 14:

[public void setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri, Map headers)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29)

Comment: It's just headers processing, but Media player doesn't work with cookie. Cookie should be ping-ponged from request to response